# Decrypting Magtek EMV Data

Tags: c#, android, encryption, emv, dukpt

basically my question is more of a "how should I approach this" than more of a code example based question....Basically I am trying to decrypt the Tag DFDF59(encrypted data tag) from a Magtek eDynamo EMV dip which has data like encrypted track 2 that I need. I am using tag DFDF56(KSN) to decrypt the data from the onTransactionResult callback. using https://www.magtek.com/content/documentationfiles/d99875728.pdf as reference. Magtek MSR works great, I can decrypt encrypted track 2 fine and I can see the clear text, it is just EMV that I am having issues with. With MSR, I basically pass in the encrypted data and the KSN into DUKPT and a clear text string is returned. Attempting to do the same with That EMV Tag but does not seem to be working. Any suggestions on how to approach this? Maybe I am not using the right Tag or not the proper KSN?Do not have much experience with EMV decryption

Comment: Check if you are using the correct key for decryption

Answer (score 0):

```
has data like encrypted track 2 that I need
```

If data is encrypted then there will be a key that will decrypt it.

It can be TDES - **Triple DES + ECB Mode** operation to decrypt the data ( Generally it works in EMV).

```
Maybe I am not using the right Tag or not the proper **KSN** ?
```

Try to get the **correct**/plain key to perform this operation, Please make sure you are using the correct key otherwise result is false always.

Hope it helps.